# A few IE6 quirks that I am unable to solve

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have been working on a site for a client and I am about to wrap it up.. but unfortunately IE6 is being a pain in the buttocks.

My main problems are on this page:

http://seaport.bythepixel.com/#storage

1. The list items dont have bullets
2. The spacing below the floated items are not being cleared correctly.  I applied "clear:both" to my h2 tags and it is clearing.. but the spacing bellow the floated items doesnt seem right.  If you compare any other browse with IE6 you will see the spacing issue I am speaking of.
3. maybe this is just an IEtester problem, but the background image I have applied to "#full" stops and starts randomly.  You can see this on the storage page and the floor plans page.  I am referring to the gray to white gradient that separates the left navigation column with the right content column.

Any help as always is greatly appreciated!

Comment: why are you concerned about supporting a 10+ year old browser?

Comment: This isn't helpful to your question, but even Microsoft is telling people to get off IE6.  Perhaps your efforts would be better spent elsewhere?  Particularly since the issues aren't fatal.

Comment: i guess im a perfectionist :(  believe when i say i would much rather not worry about it.  do you think its time to start ditching testing on ie6?

Comment: Well Roeland i usually tell clients upfront that i will make it functional in IE6 - but its not goign to look 1:1 - if you want some of the design elements implemented back to IE6 then thats extra. It makes people whos primary market insnt IE6 users think twice - and those that know what they need are more than happy to accept the extra cost and/or additions to timeline.

Comment: It really depends who your target audience is.  In a B2B world, a lot of users still have IE6 because it comes installed on Windows XP and their companies don't give them permissions to install new software.  My company's website still gets about 10% IE6 users.

Comment: IE6 has a 11% market share on a site like http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp -- which is a site targeting web developers. Do you think the average population is lower or higher?

The OP is right in trying to make sure things work for IE6 ... 10-15% is MILLIONS of potential visitors.

Comment: 'Work' and 'work perfectly', I think, is the distinction.  Where is the OP's time best spent - real product improvement or niggling over details for one market segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) and 3) are clearly the [hasLayout bugs](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html). You need to give the elements in question a "layout". Start with giving the `#full` a `position: relative;` (validates) or a `zoom: 1;` (doesn't validate).

2) is likely caused by odd use of `overflow: hidden;` here and there. Try removing it all and see if that helps.

Comment: is overflow:hidden a bad way to contain floats inside its parent containers.. (instead of using an empy div to clear the floats)

Answer (score 0):

When you set an overflow (hidden if possible) to all floated elements there might already be a lot of problems solved.

Answer (score 0):

> maybe this is just an IEtester
>   problem, but the background image I
>   have applied to "#full" stops and
>   starts randomly.

I can confirm i see this on a machine with IE6 only installed.